# UIImagePickerController trim controls not showing

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I've been unable to get the trim controls to appear when capturing an iOS movie.

Here's my code:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Additionally, I'm capturing the reply with `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`.

From searching StackOverflow I'm aware that I need to actually trim the video myself. That doesn't seem too difficult, but while I get the image picker and can capture a video I can't get the trim controls to **appear**! What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was just in using video samples that were too short. They need to be over a certain length before the trimming tools will appear.